# Vue, I want to show different text than selected option from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I am trying to create a dropdown. this is how it should look, [Example Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acc5d.png)

When someone selects the percent option then the dropdown should show a % in the selected text field.
and when vehicle count it should show #,

I am currently using el-select to make it work but no success, I am not able to understand how can I replace the selected value with another text in vue without using jquery.

Comment: Please update your question to include your attempt :) will make it easier to assist

Comment: Also do let us know if you are using any design framework like vuetify, please.